# Command parameter won't bind to a StackPanel?

Tags: .net, wpf, xaml, .net-4.0, binding

I am trying to create a simple TreeView which will represent my applications data directory, however I found that when trying to implement a folder rename option that I could not bind my command paramater on the context menu to a StackPanel.

Code:

```
<Grid>
    <Label Content="{Binding Path=FolderName}">
        <Label.ContextMenu>
        <ContextMenu>
            <MenuItem Header="Rename Folder" Command="{Binding Path=ToggleControlVisability}" CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=FolderNameEditor}"></MenuItem>
            <MenuItem Header="Delete Folder" Command="{Binding Path=DeleteFolder}" CommandParameter="{Binding Path=FolderInformation}"></MenuItem>
        </ContextMenu>
        </Label.ContextMenu>
    </Label>

    <StackPanel Name="FolderNameEditor" Orientation="Horizontal" Visibility="Hidden">
        <TextBox Name="EditFolderName" Text="{Binding Path=FolderName}"></TextBox>
        <Button Content="Ok" Command="{Binding Path=ToggleControlVisability}" CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=EditFolderName}"></Button>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

The problem seems to be the hierachy, is there some way I can use a relative source to bind the rename folder menu item command paramater to the stack panel containing the editor elements?

Thanks,

Alex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The MenuItems aren't part of the visual tree, so you must add an explicit "CommandTarget" binding to the command listener (or any descendant).

Comment: Can you give me a quick example please?